# Jacoco coverage of unit test code

Tags: maven-3, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm converting an ANT build to Maven. I don't use Sonar.

In Maven, Jacoco doesn't seem to report about coverage of the unit tests themselves, while ANT does. I've been trying to get this for my Maven build as well, but I haven't been able to find anything.

It seems like I should add an `<include>` to the `prepare-agent` goal, but I'm not sure what to include. I've tried `src/test/java/*` and all kinds of variations on that theme, but none works.

How can I configure Jacoco in Maven such that it does report the coverage of unit test code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the only way to do this, is to use the `maven-antrun-plugin`.

There's no need to add an `<include>` to the `prepare-agent` goal, because all information is present in the `jacoco.exec` file it generates, including the unit test code.

The `report` goal doesn't include it, though, and it can't be configured to use it either. You would need to specifically set the `classfiles` and `sourcefiles` properties, and the Maven Jacoco plugin won't let you do this.

Hence, you need the Maven Antrun plugin, and configure and call it from there.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <taskdef name="report" classname="org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                        <report>
                            <executiondata>
                                <file file="${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec" />
                            </executiondata>
                            <structure name="Coverage">
                                <classfiles>
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"/>
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes"/>
                                </classfiles>
                                <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                                    <fileset dir="src/main/java"/>
                                    <fileset dir="src/test/java"/>
                                </sourcefiles>
                            </structure>
                            <check failonviolation="true" violationsproperty="violation">
                                <rule element="BUNDLE">
                                    <limit counter="INSTRUCTION" value="COVEREDRATIO" minimum="0.95" />
                                </rule>
                            </check>
                            <html destdir="${project.build.directory}/jacoco-internal"/>
                        </report>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```